# Whats is a callback formula in Qlikview?

Tags: qlikview

I came across a term called callback formula. Does it any particular meaning have pertaining to qlikview ?

The general definition of callback that I found is that

> Callback is executable code that is passed as an argument to other code.

How does it correspond to formulas in Qlikview?

Comment: where did you come across a term called callback formula?

Comment: Possibly from here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @utility A client had asked about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly mean "callback formula" in QV but think that this might be a reference to the way you can pass arguments to a variable calculation.

http://qlikviewmaven.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/variable-that-acts-like-user-defined.html

Stefan